# Writing output as in the similar path of Input in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have data in a parquet file as in the below directory

```
input/data/id1/files
input/data/id2/files
input/data/id3/files
```

How do I read these data with each id as a folder name? And after reading and doing some processing how do I store the output in similar path same as input path.

```
/outout/data/id1/outputpaequet
/outout/data/id2/outputpaequet
/outout/data/id3/outputpaequet
```

Answer (score 2):

So below, status is like doing an ls on the directory. Get your list of paths back, loop through them, write them out in the similar path replacing input with output.

```
val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/input/data/"))
status.foreach(f => {
  val input = sqlContext.read.parquet(f.getPath.toString)
  val output: DataFrame = // do something
  output.write.parquet(f.getPath.toString.replace("input", "output"))
})
```

Comment: you'd probably want to clarify that you'd want to call `write` on some `val output: DataFrame = // do something` and not on the original `input` DF. Whatever `// do something` does, it can't actually change `input`, so the answer as it is now might be confusing.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. I went ahead and added it in. thanks!

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchuler